# Upload from C# to GDrive

Tags: c#, winforms, google-drive-api

Please help. I am looking for a way to upload a file to Google Drive with my app. The Google Account in question will be a specific one, i.e. not the client's account, a 'Service' account. I've tried to Google it, but I can't find anything that seems to do what I want, And the API reference I probably don't understand. I have been thrown in the deep end for a project. Any source or links to help Please! I am not asking anyone to write my source, but if it exists, it would be nice.
Note: This is my last hope. I don't ask a question unless there is nooooo other way.
(I am using Windows Forms)
Thanks

Jacques

EDIT: It is always signing in to MY drive, whether I am using it or you are using it. I have also posted this question to CodeProject to harness maximum brain power.
PermaLink: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/652006/Upload-from-Csharp-to-GDrive

Comment: Have you even tried to analyze quickstart code at: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs

Comment: I have tried this, but this requires the user to sign in. I need to sign in only to one account, My Drive. The user may not use their drive, or have access to mine. Google's term for it is a Service Account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page tells you what you need to know about authorizing a service account https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts

This page shows you the C# required to upload a file, once you have been authorized https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Treat the authorization and the uploading as two separate problems and you'll find life much easier. The end result of the authorization procedure is an access token. Give that access token the insert API and you're all set.

Comment: Thanks a million!!! My problem was the authorising bit and your first link is what I was looking for!!! I would upvote it, but I don't have enough rep points... I am a bit(very) embarrassed that I took so long to see the answer. I answered my own question on Code Project on the 29th (or so I thought) because I forgot about Overflow question... anyway... Thanks again!!!